# How do I know if the specified file has been read correctly?

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

Why does `ifstream` set the `failbit` to `1` after reading the last line of the specified file? How do I know if the specified file has been read correctly?

```
bool read_csv_file(const char* filename, vector<string>& lines, bool adding = false)
{
    if( !adding ) lines.clear();

    ifstream csvfile;
    csvfile.open(filename);

    if( csvfile.is_open() )
    {
        string line;
        while( csvfile.good() && getline(csvfile,line) )
        {
            lines.push_back(line);
            cout << "fail: " << csvfile.fail() << endl;
        }
        cout << "fail: " << csvfile.fail() << endl;
        csvfile.close();
        return (!csvfile.fail());
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your code is *far* too noisy. You can simply say `ifstream csvfile(filename); if (!csvfile) { /* error*/ return false; }` and get rid of most of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason `failbit` could be set after reading the last
line (or any line) is if there were an error in the library, and
I don't really believe it.  If `failbit` is set, it means that
you *didn't* read anything.  In your case, it will never be set
when you're in the loop; if it were set, `getline` would have
evaluated to `false`, and you wouldn't have entered the loop.
And of course, the loop terminates precisely because `getline`
fails (or would fail—normally, you would *not* test for
`good` before doing input, and if you do, consider that the
`failbit` was set, regardless, if the test fails).

The usual pattern for this sort of thing is:

```
while ( someInput ) {
    //  ...
}
if ( csvfile.bad() ) {
    //  Serious error (disk read error, etc.)...
} else if ( ! csvfile.eof() ) {
    //  Formatting error...
} else {
    //  Normal end of file...
}
```

When `someInput` is `std::getline()`, however, you will never
fail because of a formatting error, so the `else if` above will
never be true (and a lot of code treats hard disk errors as if
they were an end of file, and so ignores the `if` part as well).

Comment: Ok, it works! Should I close the file just after the `loop`, but before performing the final checks (`csvfile.bad()` and `!csvfile.eof()`)?

Comment: @enzom83 It's generally not necessary for input.  (For output, yes, since you have to test the status of the file after the close, to ensure that all data has really be transfered to the OS.)

Answer (score 2):

The fail bit is set after you run off the end of the file. Once that happens, you mustn't attempt to interpret the result of your input operation. That's perfectly fine, though, and `getline` will not set the fail bit while there's still *any* data to be read. So the following standard loop [extracts *all* the lines](http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/33695262.jpg):

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(csvfile, line); )
{
    // process "line"
}

// all done
```

Answer (score 1):

Too check for erroneous reads, you must test `badbit` using `stream.bad()`.

`Failbit` indicates failure in operation logic, and apparently `getline` sets it when reaching EOF (confirmed on my machine).

Comment: That's completely wrong (and in general, you'll almost never see `badbit`).